# How to sync bookmarks in Safari 5?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, sync, bookmarks, safari-5

Hey guys I have an iMac for work at home and a MacBook to bring to uni and stuff, and I'm trying to get my bookmarks to sync on both on them. Obviously it'll be a great plus to sync across browsers but my priority is just to sync between Safari. I'm using the latest version of Safari and am also on Snow Leopard.

I've tried Xmarks but sadly it doesn't work that well on me. For some reason it only syncs my bookmarks bar and not everything else. Besides, they're shutting down anyways so it's not exactly a long term option. Also I've heard that MobileMe works wonders but personally I can't justify forking out $99 a year just to have my bookmarks in sync.

Comment: i'm interested in this, too. AFAIK XMarks was the only solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking around I've decided to take matters into my own hands and with help from http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070721083529100, I'm gonna write a script which:

Assuming I have mac1, mac2, and server
1. Checks once an hour whether the bookmarks in mac1 is newer than the one on server
2. If yes upload to server, else do nothing
3. Download new bookmarks from server to mac2
4. Repeat 1-3 for mac2

Answer (score 0):

You could use [BookMacster](http://www.sheepsystems.com/products/bkmx/), or [Bookdog](http://www.sheepsystems.com/products/bookdog/) if you are using an older version of MacOSX.  They aren't free, but they are a lot cheaper than a MobileMe subscription.  [SyncIT](http://www.sync2it.com/) also works on Macs, which is free.

I also recommend the use of [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) for tagging bookmarks.  I have many hundreds of tagged bookmarks on Delicious, which makes it very easy for me to find anything I need, like the links I have just given you.  [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) is similar.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but none of them is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @jon2512chua:  Curious to know how they do not fit your requirements?

Comment: Well BookMacster and Bookdog are paid services, whereas SyncIT seems a bit too legacy. I like Delicious and Google Bookmarks, but I prefer keeping my bookmarks locally, it's just a quirk. Also I see the last two services as something more for keeping bookmarks of articles, which I'm already using Evernote for.

Comment: @jon2512chua:  Ah, okay.  Personally, I use a combination of Windows Live Sync Beta for local syncing of IE9 Beta favorites, Delicious for keeping note of pages I may want to refer to again, and Google Bookmarks for easy access from the Google Toolbar (which I find very handy for a variety of reasons).

Answer (score 0):

[dotMobile](http://code.google.com/p/dotmac/) is a free reimplementation for .mac / MobileMe. I don't know the exact project status (it seems to be a bit dead-ish, last commit a year ago), but you might be able to sync your bookmarks using this.